# How to turn live stream of raw frame image data into video

Tags: java, browser, video-streaming, kinect-v2

I am using J4K library to extract raw live data from kinect in java. So far I have managed to get RAW BGRA image data from kinect and convert them to PNG. Now I need to stream them into the browser as a video. So my question is any suggestions how to turn live photo frames into live video that I can stream.

This is how I receive the frames. I have no open stream nothing just frame by frame.

```
@Override
public void onColorFrameEvent(byte[] color_frame) {
    ...image processing
}
```

The client where I want to receive the video is a nodejs application but I dont think it matters here.

Comment: Do  you mean something like offline streaming?

Comment: Well its supposed to work on localhost so I dont need to stream it online...But its supposed to be over HTTP, TCP or similar. The main issue is that I am not surre if its event possible to convert continuous series of images into video and stream it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tag, i am assuming you are using Kinect-v2.

The easiest way that comes up to my mind for managing and creating the live streaming running in the browser is using [OpenKinect-for-Processing](https://github.com/shiffman/OpenKinect-for-Processing) library. It is use friendly and easy-to-use library which runs on your browser. For quick tutorial you can check this [link](http://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/) and look through this small youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmVNgdapJJM&index=1&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZMlWHdcy8hAGDy6IaoxUKf).

Comment: Hmmm this looks promising. But it still seems that it offers images per frame. I am still unsure how do I actually convert them in java and stream them over WebSockets or some other protocol.

Comment: You want to save them somehow as a video?

Comment: No I want to stream it to browser. So you can view the kinect live stream in browser as a webcam.

Comment: Yes, and this library also provides live streaming which is a sequence of frames.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how do I stream it over some protocol ?

Comment: Do you really want to play with protocols? You can modify the source code.  You can follow this path to see the information about protocols used for different purposes  OpenKinect-for-Processing/build_openKinect2/C++/libs/protonect/include/libfreenect2/protocol/ . You can also glance to these examples for getting information how to grab frames OpenKinect-for-Processing/OpenKinect-Processing/examples/Kinect_v2/

Comment: The issue here is that I have a nodejs application in which i need to display the live stream. So I am not sure that this will be exactly what I need.